# How many bootstraps does rfsrc in the R package randomforestsrc peform?

Tags: random-forest, analysis, survival

Does anyone know how many bootstraps or subsamples a standard call to rfsrc performs?

```
rf1<-rfsrc(Surv(time,status)~., data=myTable)
```

Also `rf1$err.rate` which is described as "cumulative OOB error rate" for me at the above settings is a vector of length 1000, with 999 element being `NA`and only the last element is an error rate (between 0 and 0.5). Is that the expected behaviour? Is this last value the average error of all bootstraps?

Update: I have found a setting `block.size`, which regulates how many OOB error rates out of the 1000 are returned. If you set it to e.g. 10, every thenth OOB error rate is filled. Hower what I am still not sure about is on how many bootstraps each of these error rates is calculated. Is each simply one error rate from a single bootstrap or subsample or is it somehow averaged?

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation:

> sampsize Function specifying size of bootstrap data when by.root is in
>   effect. For sampling without replacement, it is the requested size of
>   the sample, which by default is .632 times the sample size. For
>   sampling with replacement, it is the sample size. Can also be speciﬁed
>   by using a number.

So by default, sampling is done without replacement and 63.2 % of observations are sampled randomly for each tree in the forest.

Comment: @StanW Yes, each tree gets its own bootstrap sample.